# How to add text to matplotlib plot from a figure object?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

My code contains the following lines:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

figure = Figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=dpi)
```

How can I add text to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texts can be added from a axis object. So you may try this:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
figure = Figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=dpi)
ax = figure.add_axes((0.05, 0.05, 0.9, 0.9))
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Text', ha='center')
```

More examples can see [the document](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text), and details of parameters [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)